# New Report and Dashboard Folder Sharing Settings API Access

Tags: reporting, api

Is it posible to access the new sharing settings for reports and dashboards? We have lots of folders and it would be nice to be able to update them using Data Loader instead of one by one.

I'm specifically looking for an object that is exposed that shows what users, groups and roles have been added to a folder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can export and update some level of the permissions on report folders.

With dataloader you can export the "Folder" object.

- Select the export option and chose "Show all salesforce object"
- There will now be a object called "Folder", these are the report, dashboard, email, document folders, the type is shown in the export.
- You can edit the following

  - AccessType - Public, PublicInternal, Shared, Hidden
  - Readonly - True/False
- Perform an Update through dataloader to update these values.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the settings where you share with users, roles, groups, etc.

Comment: OK, so where you specify that this Folder is shared with CEO, Sales, etc. This is only accessible through the UI I belive.

Comment: You can access this data through the FolderShare object available in the Metadata API. You can edit and update the values using offline tools. grep and perl are likely going to be your friend here, because it's all XML-based, not a flat file.