# Automated way of setting up report folder permissions to users when implementing "Fine-Grained Sharing for Report and Dashboard Folders" feature

Tags: reporting

Is there any automated way of setting up report folder permissions to users while implementing the new "Fine-Grained Sharing for Report and Dashboard Folders" feature

The permission needs to be set at a user level.  Can i use dataloader/any other tool to set the permissions.   The data i load should populate the table below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I asked the [same question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13236/new-report-and-dashboard-folder-sharing-settings-api-access?rq=1) not too long ago. I believe the answer is no. I haven't been able to find any API objects that seem to do the trick.